# BERT Domain Adaptation

Tags: python, nlp, pytorch, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model

I am using `transformers.BertForMaskedLM` to further pre-train the BERT model on my custom dataset. I first serialize all the text to a `.txt` file by separating the words by a whitespace. Then, I am using `transformers.TextDataset` to load the serialized data with a BERT tokenizer given as `tokenizer` argument. Then, I am using `BertForMaskedLM.from_pretrained()` to load the pre-trained model (which is what `transformers` library presents). Then, I am using `transformers.Trainer` to further pre-train the model on my custom dataset, i.e., domain adaptation, for 3 epochs. I save the model with `trainer.save_model()`. Then, I want to load the further pre-trained model to get the embeddings of the words in my custom dataset. To load the model, I am using `AutoModel.from_pretrained()` but this pops up a warning.

```
Some weights of the model checkpoint at {path to my further pre-trained model} were not used when initializing BertModel
```

So, I know why this pops up. Because I further pre-trained using `transformers.BertForMaskedLM` but when I load with `transformers.AutoModel`, it loads it as `transformers.BertModel`. What I do not understand is if this is a problem or not. I just want to get the embeddings, e.g., embedding vector with a size of 768.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You saved a `BERT` model with LM head attached. Now you are going to load the serialized file into a standalone `BERT` structure without any extra element and the warning is issued. This is pretty normal and there is no Fatal error to do so! You can check the list of unloaded params like below:

```
from transformers import BertTokenizer, BertModel
from transformers import BertTokenizer, BertLMHeadModel, BertConfig
import torch

lmbert = BertLMHeadModel.from_pretrained('bert-base-cased', config=config)
lmbert.save_pretrained('you_desired_path/BertLMHeadModel')
lmbert_params = []
for name, param in lmbert.named_parameters():
    lmbert_params.append(name)
bert = BertModel.from_pretrained('you_desired_path/BertLMHeadModel')
bert_params = []
for name, param in bert.named_parameters():
    bert_params.append(name)
params_ralated_to_lm_head = [param_name for param_name in lmbert_params if param_name.replace('bert.', '') not in bert_params]
params_ralated_to_lm_head
```

output:

```
['cls.predictions.bias',
 'cls.predictions.transform.dense.weight',
 'cls.predictions.transform.dense.bias',
 'cls.predictions.transform.LayerNorm.weight',
 'cls.predictions.transform.LayerNorm.bias']
```

Comment: Thanks. So, the attached LM head is not being initialized, right? I do not need that LM head, I just need BERT last hidden state embeddings. Thus, everything is alright, right?

Comment: Yes! There is a library named [SentenceTransformer](https://www.sbert.net/) which is part of `huggingface` amazing work and lets you do various analyses on the embedded texts